# How to refer successfully compiled scala class in scala script file?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ.

To compiled my .scala file, at command prompt, and it created Item.Class file.

In IntelliJ, I created scala script file and tried to Instantiate the Item object

```
  Item("Jacket", 10)
```

It says "Cannot resolve Item". I know this is a basic question. What is the best way to reference a compiled class in script files?

```
  case class Item (name:String, quantity:Int) extends AnyVal{

 }
```

Comment: If you have scala plugin installed, it should be easy to create a scala file and define the class there

Comment: Your Item class doesn't compile.  Value classes can only have one parameter.

Comment: How are you running your script?  Is the class file on the classpath?  Did you import your class?  Does it work if you make a regular scala program with a main method?

Comment: When I say Import Item in the script file, it still says "Cannot resolve Item".

Comment: I am confused. What is the difference between, .sc and .scala file?

Comment: `.sc` is scala worksheet(same as .scala), but will be evaluated on your IDE. Easy to debug while learning as you can see each of your variables evaluated right away - https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started#getting-started